# White Spaces between url link

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsstring

```
NSString* str = [inventoryDetails objectAtIndex:i];
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(j, 10, 280, 180)];

if (![str isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[inventoryDetails objectAtIndex:i] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
```

I'm getting output as

> https:google.com/images/320.png

How to remove the space in url

Comment: Where do strings of `inventoryDetails` come from? That's where the problem is.

Comment: why has not the scheme been defined properly as `http://...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"http://...";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trim your NSString if your space are on the sides.

```
NSString *trimMe = @"    Trim this string      ";
trimMe = [trimMe stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"Trimmed String: ++%@++", trimMe);
//returnes Trimmed String: ++Trim this string+++
```

Comment: Hi the url is fetched from server,so plz help in removing the spaces of url from server dynamically